# In which order the payment method and total amount should present?

Tags: design, mobile-application, checkout, shopping-cart, payment

I am currently working on the payments process for a mobile application.I've run into a UX problem when designing the payment screen.

Is there a convention for the order which payment method and total amount should present?

Please help me to choose one version.

---

[image]

Comment: If you're asking about conventions, you can just visit some commerce websites. (That's what I do when I want to find out "best practices" or current conventions.) If you've done that already, could you tell us your results and why those results are inconclusive? That would help steer our answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I'm designing for e-commerce for many years, through some tests I found out that the price is the most important thing in the checkout process, whilst everything close to purchase button attracts more attention.

What users want to know is the price so they look for it even if it's not in the right place. And what they need to know is the payment method which should be in the right place.

So I strongly recommend V1.